# SpriteKit: Collisions with 300 nodes, very low FPS

Tags: ios, performance, 2d

I want to make a simple SpriteKit app where I can add "rocks" and they fall to bottom of the screen. Just like this: http://aamukasa.fi/II-13-347. The implementation is quite easy but I will get huge performance issues when there are more than 100 nodes. The FPS goes under 10 when all the blocks collides together. Is there anyway to achieve this kind of functionality with good FPS and about 300-400 blocks?

```
@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;


}
return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */

for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

    SKSpriteNode *rock = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor blackColor]     size:CGSizeMake(20,10)];
    rock.position = location;
    rock.name = @"rock";
    rock.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:rock.size];
    [self addChild:rock];

}
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

Comment: I recently abandoned SpriteKit on my current project and replaced it with cocos2d. The performance is extraordinarily better with cocos2d, and you can use it with Box2D for some basic physics. I highly recommend giving this a go and seeing how well that handles your scenario.

Comment: I've actually tested this with cocos2d too. The performance is little bit better, but far away of what I need. The cocos2d is more complicated and the SpriteKit would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try to give your rocks a circular physicsbody. I don't think it will solve the issue but might increase framerate a bit! As far as I've understood, circular physicsbodies are better for performance than rectangular ones.

Comment: I tried and actually it's a bit better. It still is not enough for me. I think this is just unrealistic to achieve this kind of functionality with this kind of hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You should test on a device to see actual FPS. In the simulator I get 60 FPS until I reach 200 bricks.

Then it starts dropping but on the device you could get better results.

Comment: Yes of course. Actually the performance is worse in device than in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking, but could try something like this:

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics
{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"rock" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        if (node.position.y < 0)
            [node removeFromParent];
    }];
}
```

Otherwise the nodes will stay in memory and FPS will worsen overtime.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think this won't help, because the rocks will be visible all the time